# Is it possible to make a character and return what that character's value in the the global environment?

Tags: r

I am not sure if this is possible but I would like to return the global environment value of each element in a vector that was generated using `sprintf`.

```
v1 <- 'value 1'
v2 <- 'value 2'
v3 <- 'value 3'

obs <- noquote(sprintf('%s%d', 'v', 1:3))
obs
```

obs returns:

```
[1] v1 v2 v3
```

But I would like it to return the value of c(v1, v2, v3):

```
[1] "value 1" "value 2" "value 3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
mget(obs)
# $v1
# [1] "value 1"
# $v2
# [1] "value 2"
# $v3
# [1] "value 3"
unlist(mget(obs))
#        v1        v2        v3 
# "value 1" "value 2" "value 3"
```